# Stop Link Use Changing Styles of Button / Typography with React Router and MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating component that I want to be clickable - however, when I either wrap them in a `<Link>` (from react-router-dom) or set `component={Link} to=""` on them, then any text inside them become hyperlinks. Example:

[image]

Above are four buttons, the last three are wrapped in `<Link>` tags, but I don't want the styling of those changed. I know I can remove the underline etc using styling - but I shouldn't have to do that for everything inside the link tag.

I also get this when I add `component={Link} to=""` to a container which has images, and Typography inside - and all the text becomes hyperlinked too.

How can I stop everything inside a Link being styled as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to go about this. Check out [MUI: How to customize](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/) as a reference.

If you don't want any `Link` components on your site at all to look like that, then you may simply use a `theme` override:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiLink: {
      root: {
        // ...
      },
    }
  }
});
```

If you just need this section to have links look differently, then you may just want to use a simply reusable component that's styled once. Something along these lines:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Link, { LinkProps } from '@mui/material/Link';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const SimpleLink = styled(Link)<LinkProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  textDecoration: 'none'
}));

export default function StyledCustomization(url: string) {
  return <SimpleLink url={url} />;
}
```